# Disable audio route changes in an iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, bluetooth

I have an audio app that plays for many hours throughout the night.  Sometimes the iPhone changes routes and says the speaker is no longer available and stops playing audio.  I'm not sure why but my theory is that it tried to connect to a Bluetooth device.  I get the following in the log:

AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonCategoryChange
AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable

And since the old device is no longer available it stops the audio.  I'm playing audio through the iPhone speaker, so I'm not sure why the speaker would no longer be be available.

My question is what can I do to prevent this from happening in code?  I advise people to turn on Airplane mode or disable Bluetooth which always fixes the issue.  I'm wondering if something could be done in code to help solve this problem.

Comment: Try to disable bluetooth? You cannot diagnose a problem without knowing what causes it. Also recording your device and seeing when it happens will be your only option afterwards. Usually switching audio output devices doesnt stop any audio but only **changes the output**

Comment: Yes, turning off bluetooth or enabling Airplane mode is what we tell people to do and it seems to fix it.  Looking for a code solution to this...

Comment: Only finding the bug,and being able to recreate it will let you find the solution to it.